# launching atom text editor linux !# . GLIBC_2.14 and GLIBC_2.15 not found?

Tags: dependencies, debian, glibc, libc, atom-editor

I am using crunnchbang linux 64 bit. I installed atom text editor but its giving errors when I try to launch it. The output is as follows:

```
shunya@crunchbang:~$ atom 
shunya@crunchbang:~$ /usr/share/atom/atom: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/atom/atom)
/usr/share/atom/atom: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/atom/libchromiumcontent.so)
/usr/share/atom/atom: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/share/atom/libgcrypt.so.11)
/usr/share/atom/atom: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /usr/share/atom/libgcrypt.so.11)
```

Its clear from the output that it needs some packages called GLIBC_2.5 and 2.14. How can I install these requirements?
I tried to search on synaptic package manager if I search for GLIBC there is long list of packages. I am unable to tell which one to install from.

But as soon as I do GLIBC_2.14 OR -2.14 there are no options left.

*update: On trying

```
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

I get the output as libc6 is already the newest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Its clear from the output that it needs some packages called GLIBC_2.5 and 2.14.

That is incorrect. What it does need is a glibc package that is at least version 2.15 (current glibc release is 2.21).

> `sudo apt-get install libc6`
>   I get the output as libc6 is already the newest version.

What *is* that version? You can find out by running `dpkg -l libc6`.

It's likely that crunnchbang linux was based on debian 7 (wheezy) which was based on glibc-2.13.

Since a given distribution usually does not update the version of `glibc`, the latest version *on that distribution* will continue to be glibc-2.13. So your options are:

- use some other text editor, or
- upgrade your OS to some other distribution, or
- find and install `atom` that was built for older distribution, or
- compile `atom` from source, or
- build a newer glibc from source

Be extra careful with that last approach: making a mistake while building or installing system glibc is a very easy way to render your machine unbootable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately crunchbang Waldrof (the current os I am using) is based on (debian 7) can not be updated to GLIBC_2.15 
Trying to install GLIBC_2.15 can break the system.

The new version of debian (debian 8 Jessie) is released which does support GLIBC_2.15. So one option is update to debian 8.

Comment: How is that answer different from what I told you 4 days ago?